# Expected vector but found struct collections::vec::Vec

Tags: rust

I just started learning Rust and I stumbled upon this stupid problem:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `&[u8]` but found `&collections::vec::Vec<u8>` (expected vector but found struct collections::vec::Vec)
```

My code looks like this:

```rust
let compressed_contents = match File::open(&Path::new(path)).read_to_end() {
    Ok(f) => f,
    Err(e) => fail!("File error: {}", e),
};
let contents = inflate_bytes(&compressed_contents);
```

It's expecting a vector and I'm giving it a vector. Obviously there gotta be some other type of vector it wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's expecting a vector and I'm giving it a vector.

No, you got it wrong :) It's expecting a *slice* and you're giving it a vector. Use `as_slice()` method to obtain `&[u8]` from `Vec<u8>`:

```
let contents = inflate_bytes(compressed_contents.as_slice());
```

Comment: Why does the error message say `expected vector but found X`?

Comment: @KaiSellgren, sorry, but I don't see how the error message says it. It says ``expected `&[u8]` but ...``, but `&[T]` is a slice, not a vector.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev At the very end of the error message it does indeed say `(expected vector but found struct collections::vec::Vec)`.

Comment: @ChrisJones, ah, sorry, you're absolutely right, shame on me. That's definitely a leftover in the compiler which no one bothered to clean up. Until recently (and maybe even now) it printed `Box<T>` as `~T` and `Gc<T>` as `@T` in some of its error messages, despite that this syntax is *long* gone.